# table bigger space vertically than horizontally

Tags: html, css, html-table, spacing

I can't seem to figure out why my vertical spacing appears to be larger than the horizontal spacing. Is there a hidden CSS style I need to apply?

Here is sample code (below, or direct link: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FGK16ROO32ZA). You can see the space between the cells left and right is narrow but the space between the cells top and bottom is bigger:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

table,
th,
tr,
td {
  border: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-padding: 0px;
}

img {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></th>
    <th><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></th>
    <th><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></td>
    <td><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></td>
    <td><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></td>
    <td><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></td>
    <td><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There is no `border-padding` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images have a small gap below them (a space left for [descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender)). Remove it by setting their display property to block or floating them:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

table,
th,
tr,
td {
  border: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

img {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></th>
    <th><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></th>
    <th><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></td>
    <td><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></td>
    <td><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></td>
    <td><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></td>
    <td><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And as I noted in my comment to your question, there is no border-padding property so you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to table, th, tr, td{} css:

```
 padding: 2.5px 5px;
```

Adjust numbers according to what you need

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FGK1A71MO7PN

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding: 0 2px 0 2px; to make it even.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

table,
th,
tr,
td {
  border: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
}
img {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></th>
    <th><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></th>
    <th><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></td>
    <td><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></td>
    <td><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></td>
    <td><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></td>
    <td><img src="https://www.elie.net/image/public/1495321502/learn-web-security-with-google.png"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

html table rows and column are flexible unless you defined the height and width value. As I can see you have given width and height of image which is not proportional to original image height and width. I would suggest following way to style the image height or width.

```
img{
width: 128px;
/*height must be proportional to width otherwise image get stretch*/
}
```

I hope this will help you out.